# The type parameter T is hiding the type T

Tags: java, android

My question is: why, if i use LinearLayout, instead of `Object`, as "Result" of my `AsyncTask` (`TableWithinExpListTask<Params, Progress, LinearLayout>`) , Eclipse give me many errors like *Cannot instantiate the type LinearLayout*?
It seems to me that it doesn't recognise `LinearLayout` anymore in `createFormattedCell()` and i can't undertstand why.
In the `AsyncTask` declaration `LinearLayout` has yellow underline and Eclipse says: **The type parameter LinearLayout is hiding the type LinearLayout**.
Please someone can explain this to me?

Here is the code of the class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TableWithinExpListTask<Params, Progress, LinearLayout> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, LinearLayout> {

    private final int TABLE_BORDER = 1;
    private final int TABLE_TEXT_PADDING = 10;


    private Context context = null;
    private String str = null;
    private boolean tableHeader = false;
    private LinearLayout column = null;

    public TableWithinExpListTask(Context context, String str, boolean tableHeader, LinearLayout column) {
        this.context = context;
        this.str = str;
        this.tableHeader = tableHeader;
        this.column = column;
    }

    @Override
    protected LinearLayout doInBackground(Params... arg0) {
        return this.createFormattedCell(this.tableHeader, this.str);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(LinearLayout result) {
        this.column.addView(result);
    }

    private LinearLayout createFormattedCell(boolean tabHeader, String str) {
        // Layout che circonda le textView necessario per disegnare il bordo
        // delle celle
        LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(this.context);

        container.setPadding(TABLE_BORDER, TABLE_BORDER, 0, 0);
        container.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this.context);

        textView.setPadding(TABLE_TEXT_PADDING, TABLE_TEXT_PADDING, TABLE_TEXT_PADDING, TABLE_TEXT_PADDING);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);

        if (tabHeader) {
            textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            textView.setBackgroundColor(this.context.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_grayish_orange));
        }
        textView.setText(str);
        container.addView(textView);

        return container;
    }


}
```

I see other question about this but i don't fully understand this behavior in this case.

Comment: Why do you downvoted my question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having the generic parameters (the stuff in angle brackets) attached to the name of your class is telling Java that you want users of your class to be able to specify the types involved, and you're using those names as the "variable names" for the types those users choose. See, for example, `Map<K,V>`, where `K` and `V` represent the types of the `Map`'s keys and values. When you listed `LinearLayout` as a type parameter, the compiler thought that you were just using it as a placeholder for some other class that users would pick, and it didn't know how to construct one.

You're wanting your concrete class to extend a class that uses generics, but you know the specific types that you want to fill in there, so you don't put type parameters on your own class, just on the one you're using. For example, if you were writing a custom `Map` class that only mapped `String`s to `Integer`s, you would say `public class MyMap implements Map<String, Integer>`.

Answer (score 2):

Change the whole code to this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TableWithinExpListTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, LinearLayout> {

    private final int TABLE_BORDER = 1;
    private final int TABLE_TEXT_PADDING = 10;

    private Context context = null;
    private String str = null;
    private boolean tableHeader = false;
    private LinearLayout column = null;

    public TableWithinExpListTask(Context context, String str,
            boolean tableHeader, LinearLayout column) {
        this.context = context;
        this.str = str;
        this.tableHeader = tableHeader;
        this.column = column;
    }

    @Override
    protected LinearLayout doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        return this.createFormattedCell(this.tableHeader, this.str);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(LinearLayout result) {
        this.column.addView(result);
    }

    private LinearLayout createFormattedCell(boolean tabHeader, String str) {
        // Layout che circonda le textView necessario per disegnare il bordo
        // delle celle
        LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(this.context);

        container.setPadding(TABLE_BORDER, TABLE_BORDER, 0, 0);
        container.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this.context);

        textView.setPadding(TABLE_TEXT_PADDING, TABLE_TEXT_PADDING,
                TABLE_TEXT_PADDING, TABLE_TEXT_PADDING);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);

        if (tabHeader) {
            textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            textView.setBackgroundColor(this.context.getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.light_grayish_orange));
        }
        textView.setText(str);
        container.addView(textView);

        return container;
    }

}
```

I believe also you would need to have a loot a bit at Java generics. I would start to read the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) for this.

Comment: ok i'll try your code, but please can you explain why is it giving me those kind of errors?

Comment: Because the way you wrote it before `LinearLayout` was not referring to `android.widget.LinearLayout` but you were introducing a generic placeholder with same name. Placeholders are supposed to be used in class definitions. When you extend from a class that was defined with generic placeholders you will provide concrete or close to (`?`/`? extends SomeClass`) class references. Again: these are subject for generics, you really need to study that tutorial. :)

Comment: I think because SE only allows one accepted answer, and the question was asking for an explanation, not a fix per se.

Comment: @gunar I accepted chrylis answer because imho it is more easy to get as explanation. Anyway i upvoted yours for the code example and for the tutorial link.