# How to properly implement java.util.Collection class ?

Tags: java, eclipse, collections

I want to write my own Linked-list< T> and implement java.util.Collection< T>.

My problem is the warning: **"The type parameter T is hiding the type T"**. that occures when I override the method `public <T> T[] toArray(T[] arg0){}`

Here's my code:

```
public class MyLinkedList<T>  implements Serializable,Iterable<T>, Collection<T>
{
    //some constructor here.  

    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] arg0)  // I get that error here under the <T> declaration
    {
        return null;
    }
    ...
    // all other methods 
    ...
}
```

(I know I can extend AbstractCollection class instead but that's not what I want to do).

Anybody have any idea how to solve this?
Should I change the parameter T in **Collection< T>** to be some other letter like so: `Collection< E>` ?

Comment: give the method type parameter a different name other than `T`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Troubleshooting "The type parameter T is hiding the type T" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011758/troubleshooting-the-type-parameter-t-is-hiding-the-type-t-warning)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296908/java-generics-the-type-parameter-t-is-hiding-the-type-t

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121406/the-type-parameter-t-is-hiding-the-type-t

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548205/the-type-parameter-t-is-hiding-the-type-t-in-t-t-toarrayt-a-using-eclips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because method `<T> T[] toArray(T[] arg0)` takes a generic parameter of its own, which is independent of the generic parameter `T` of your class.

If you need both types `T` (of the class) and `T` (of the method) to be available inside `toArray` implementation, you need to rename one of these types. For example, Java reference implementations use `E` (for "element") as the generic type argument of collection classes:

```
public class MyLinkedList<E>  implements Serializable, Iterable<E>, Collection<E>
{
    //some constructor here.  

    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    ...
    // all other methods 
    ...
}
```

Now the names of the two generic parameters are different, which fixes the problem.